# Escape sequence not working for ']' in oracle plsql

Tags: oracle, plsql

```sql
SELECT 'VALID' FROM DUAL WHERE REGEXP_LIKE ('[', '^([[ABC[]*)$');
-- This will return the expected result VALID.

SELECT 'VALID' FROM DUAL WHERE REGEXP_LIKE (']', '^([[ABC\]]*)$');
-- This is not returning the expected result.
```

Please help to advise how to use escape sequence for square bracket ']'

Comment: I need to evaluate a value in a field and i need to give valid values if it doesn't have below values '!%^&*{}[]'. If any data have value as above mentioned special character, i need to give it as Invalid

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As per [documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/SQLRF/ap_posix001.htm#SQLRF55540), place the "]" first in the list.

`SELECT 'VALID' FROM DUAL WHERE REGEXP_LIKE (']', '^([]ABC]*)$');`

Comment: Hi Koen, I have updated the question. Please help to check and update with characters in value

Comment: Edited with other characters

Comment: `^[][ABC]*$` if you want to match opening square brackets too.

Answer (score 1):

In the second query you match `[` to `]`. Certainly it won't work.
Fix it:

```
SELECT 'VALID' FROM DUAL WHERE REGEXP_LIKE (']', '^([]]*)$');
```

**UPDATE**:
If you just want to check that certain characters are not in a string, you need `REGEXP_INSTR` instead. If this function returns a number > 0 it means a character is in the string. You may try this:

```
SELECT REGEXP_INSTR ('[ABC]', '\[|\]|[!%^&*{}]') FROM DUAL;
```

Comment: Ankit, I have updated the question. Please check. Your answer is not working for scenario where it has other characters

Comment: @CHANDRUS, what is the problem you're trying to solve? Are you sure you need `REGEXP_LIKE` and not `REGEXP_INSTR`?

Comment: Hi Pavel, I need to evaluate a value in a field and i need to give valid values if it doesn't have below vaues'!%^&*{}[]'. If any data have value as above mentioned special character, i need to give it as Invalid

Comment: @CHANDRUS, check the answer.

Answer (score 1):

For [

```
SELECT 'VALID' FROM DUAL WHERE REGEXP_LIKE ('[[[[', '^\[+$');
```

For ]

```
SELECT 'VALID' FROM DUAL WHERE REGEXP_LIKE (']]]]', '^\]+$');
```

For ][

```
SELECT 'VALID' FROM DUAL WHERE REGEXP_LIKE (']]]]', '^(\]|\[)+$');
```

With ABC simbols:

```
SELECT 'VALID' FROM DUAL WHERE REGEXP_LIKE (']]hfbgie]]', '^[a-zA-Z]|(]|[)]+$')
```

Comment: Hi Rustam, I have updated the question. Please help to check and update with characters in value.

Comment: try this SELECT 'VALID' FROM DUAL WHERE REGEXP_LIKE (']]hfbgie]]', '^[a-zA-Z]|(\]|\[)]+$')